# VIM: Use the working directory in a path setting

Tags: vim, dictionary, thesaurus

Basically, what I'm trying to do is have VIM search for dictionary/thesaurus results using **dictionary.txt** and **thesaurus.txt** in the **current working directory**.

So what I've tried in vimrc is something like:

> set thesaurus=:pwd/thesaurus.txt

without much luck.

Has anyone gotten something like this to work?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`:set thesaurus=thesaurus.txt` seems to work for me. It's already relative to the current working directory.

Comment: Wow, I was way over-thinking it lol. Duh... Thanks a bunch :)

Answer (score 0):

You should try with a dot:

```
set thesaurus=./thesaurus.txt
```

See `:help path`.

Comment: Actually I'm wrong. `./something` means roughly "in the same directory as the current file" which may or may not be the same directory as the working directory.